# Alarm android application

Tags: java, android, alarm

can anyone help me to solve my problem, 
I've to make the alarm goes off after 10 minutes from current time and it must be repeated for each 10 minutes I wrote this code but it didn't work, it start in random :"

```
public class AlarmNewActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    Intent intent;
    PendingIntent sender;
     AlarmManager am;
     Button bStart, bStop ;
     long mCurrentTime, firstTime ;
     Calendar calendar;
     TextView tv;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        bStart = (Button) findViewById (R.id.button1);
        bStop = (Button) findViewById (R.id.button2);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.textView1);

        intent = new Intent(AlarmNewActivity.this, RepeatingAlarm.class);
        sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(AlarmNewActivity.this, 0, intent, 0);
        am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());


        mCurrentTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis();


        bStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                tv.setText(""+ firstTime + "\n" + mCurrentTime );

                am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                        mCurrentTime + 10 *1000, 5*1000, sender);
               new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                         bStop.performClick();
                    }
                }, ( mCurrentTime + 50 * 1000 )); 

            }
        });


        //==================================================================================

        bStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                am.cancel(sender);
            }
        });
     }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

mCurrentTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis();

Should be inside the onClick to get the current time when clicked

```
public void onClick(View v) {

mCurrentTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
...
...
}
```

Comment: thanks alot that works and I must put  calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis()); inside the button too .. so appreciated thanks..

Comment: can you see this please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10485358/stopping-alarm-android-application