# Stopping Alarm Android Application

Tags: java, android, alarm

Can anyone tell me how can I stop this alarm?

I'm trying to stop it by using a handler but it didn't stop it continues to repeat?

Here's my code:

//=================================== After Updating =================================

```
     Button bStart, bStop ;
     long mCurrentTime;
     Calendar calendar;
     TextView tv;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        bStart = (Button) findViewById (R.id.button1);
        bStop = (Button) findViewById (R.id.button2);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.textView1);

        final Intent intent = new Intent(AlarmNewActivity.this, RepeatingAlarm.class);
        final  PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(AlarmNewActivity.this, 0, intent, 0);
        final AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);



        bStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
                mCurrentTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
                //tv.setText(""+ mCurrentTime );

                 new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                             bStop.performClick();
                             tv.setText(""+ mCurrentTime );
                        }
                    }, ( mCurrentTime + 30 * 1000 ));
                am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                        mCurrentTime + 10 *1000, 5*1000, sender);


            }
        });



        //==================================================================================

        bStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                am.cancel(sender);
            }
        });
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

make alarm manager global so that the various functions are referencing the same object

```
 Button bStart, bStop ;
     long mCurrentTime;
     Calendar calendar;
     TextView tv;
     AlarmManager am
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

       ...
       ...

        Intent intent = new Intent(AlarmNewActivity.this, RepeatingAlarm.class);
        PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(AlarmNewActivity.this, 0, intent, 0);
        am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

        .....
```

Comment: how about setting am final too ? same reason

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use the following command passing your pending intent:

```
am.cancel(yourPendingIntent);
```

I have written a good tutorial on AlarmManager some months ago that you can find at this [link](http://alchemiaandroid.altervista.org/pagina-92229.html)

Comment: thanks for ur response but i want to stop the alarm @ specific time :"

Comment: I think that you can schedule another singular alarm that cancel your old repeated alarms. That's because if your activity is closed you cannot have any control on it. Another alternative could be a service, but I think that's so stupid and weight.

Comment: thanks again, i'm trying to do another alarm but i don't know, can you explain more please !